# How can I prevent non-SAN TLS certificates from bypassing name constraints?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, x.509

I'm trying to create a private CA and want it to only be able to issue certificates for my domain via name constraints.

However, even if I create the CA with restrictions on DNS names as well as directory names like this

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My\ -Type Custom -KeyUsage CertSign,CRLSign -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(100) -Subject "CN=My Root,DC=mydomain,DC=tld" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.19={critical}{text}ca=true&pathlength=0", "2.5.29.30={critical}{text}subtree=Include&DNS=mydomain.tld&DNS=.mydomain.tld&Email=@mydomain.tld&Email=.mydomain.tld&upn=@mydomain.tld&upn=.mydomain.tld&DirectoryName=DC=mydomain,DC=tld")
```

I can still generate TLS certificates for other domains that do not fail validation by not specifying a SAN field and appending DC components to the subject's distinguished name like this

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My\ -Type SSLServerAuthentication -Signer Cert:\CurrentUser\My\<ca_cert_id> -Subject "cn=someotherdomain.com,dc=mydomain,dc=tld"
```

Is there a way to specify directory name constraints to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of issues.

1. You should use specialized CA software instead on PowerShell scripts. Even for testing, because you cannot make fully functional tests in real-world scenarios.
2. Since you haven't specified specified SAN extension in leaf certificate, then subject is used for name validation if client application agrees to. No modern browser will accept a certificate without SAN extension, thus your certificate will fail validation in these applications because of missing SAN extension (not related to name constraints). However non-browser applications (various types of HTTP/SSL Stream clients) are not required to follow CAB Forum baseline requirements and can fall back to Subject field.
3. Only `DirectoryName` name type in name constraints apply to Subject field, because Subject field is in a form of DirectoryName. In your setup, anything under `DC=mydomain,DC=tld` X.500 subtree (to the left of the string) is permitted. Since leaf certificate falls under this permission, thus Subject is technically valid.

What you should do here is to define SAN extension in leaf certificate which will completely invalidate Subject field and restrict fallback to Subject field.

See [RFC 5280 §4.2.1.10](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.10) for more details about name constraints.

And consider the response from @garethTheRed. You shall not apply any sort of constraints or restrictions on root certificate, they must be applied at lower levels. The purpose of root certificate is to provide trust anchor functionality.

Comment: Firefox is modern and still accepts cert without SAN, and TTBOMK so does Safari.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 by default?

Comment: The whole point of me going out of my way to add name constraints to the CA is to limit damage in case a malicious actor gained access to the private key. Such a malicious actor would definitely issue certs without SAN if that allowed him to get around the DNS name constraints. The question is: how can I specify `DirectoryName` constraints to prevent the CN to point to any domain other than mine?

Comment: You can't do this with `DirectoryName` name type constraints. And if attacker gained access to CAs private key -- your CA is compromised with unfortunate consequences. And name constraints is your least problem here.

Comment: If a malicious actor gained access to your private key, then it's game over.  If you are really that concerned, create a very secure offline Root CA, then an online Issuing CA onto which your name constraints are applied.

Comment: RFC 2818 states _If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST be used as the identity_.  Therefore, if you just stick to DNS names in a SAN extension and forget the whole Common Name piece, it should work for all conforming relying parties.  Assuming you're using the certs for HTTPS of course.

Comment: @Crypt32: Firefox: yes. Safari: I don't use myself and have only seen reports by others, but none has _mentioned_ it being nondefault.

Answer (score 0):

You don't apply name constraints to the root CA certificate. It asigns name constraints to certificates it issues.

There's no guarantee or expectation that name constraints or other extensions in root CA certificates are honoured.

Comment: Yes there is -- rfc5280 6.1.2 b and c. It is more _common_ to add name constraints at an intermediate below the root, but it is possible on the root, especially if you want to issue EEs/leaves directly under the root (not allowed for a cabforum CA, and usually not a good idea for a private one, but possible).

Comment: @dave-thompson-085 re "especially if you want to issue EEs/leaves directly under the root" can you please explain why name constraints are useful there?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - the _common_ assumption there is that all trust-anchors are certificates.  If the relying party used the Subject Name and Public Key only, any additional information in the certificate would be lost.  For example, the Java TrustAnchor class and RFC 5914 TustAnchorInfo.

Comment: Why do I not apply constraints to the root? I have a domain and am creating a private CA: everything I would be issuing certificates for is going to live under this domain and there is no legitimate case in which my CA would be issuing certs for external domains. I do not want the cert to be used to spoof google.com or my bank for example.

Comment: In your use case, a DNS name constraint on the Root CA cert may well work as you would/should have some reasonable control of the relying parties and therefore should know if they're using certificates for their trust-anchors and if those relying parties take heed of all extensions in the Root CA cert.

Comment: gareth: 5914 explicitly includes the validation-related extensions that could be in a root cert, including NameConstraints, with explicit reference to 5280. AFAICT (I wasn't using it then) Java baked its API design for CertPath before even 2459 in 1999, at a time when most certs (and I'm pretty sure all public roots) were v1 with no extensions.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - but all bar _pubKey_ and _keyId_ are OPTIONAL.  I'm sure that in the real-world, this isn't an issue as I doubt [m]any relying party implementations are using _TrustAnchorInfo_ for trust-anchors, but I think it's wise to play safe and place as little as possible in the Root CA cert and apply any policies/constraints in sub CAs.